# concatenate and precompile assets in new layout using rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

When I use the application layout, the .js files already get concatenated and compressed in production environment. How about if i have a new layout on a different controller, How can I concatenate the .js files like in application layout?

And also for the css can I also merge it it to 1 file?

Answer (score 1):

## Controller

```
class ThingsController < ...
```

## View

Let's say in `app/views/things/index.html.haml`

```
= javascript_include_tag 'things'
```

## Assets

In `app/assets/javascripts/things.js`

```
//= require file_1
//= require file_2
//= require file_3
```

This way file_1, file_2 and file_3 will be included in things.js

## Configuration

In production

```
config.assets.precompile << 'things.js'
```

Comment: found a solution here http://rubysnippets.com/2013/01/08/managing-the-asset-pipeline-in-rails-3/